# Ionic project doesn't build

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ionic project on github (private).  On the computer which I created it on I can build/serve/run the app (web or on android).

I've cloned the repo to another computer and done `npm install` to get all dependencies. On the second computer all of these actions, serve/run specifically run, output no errors, but then don't seem to actually be performing the build step.  The app loads a blank page and errors in console say that the files do not exist.  I can see that they don't on the filesystem.

I've even tried clone the repo to another location on the original computer, and it also will not serve/run from this location (after running `nmp install`).  So I know it is not an envirmonet set up issue, something is just not working correctly in one of the folders.

Is there some other command I need to run to prep the other locations to serve and run the app correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone encounters a similar issue, this is what I did to fix it:
I upgraded to the latest version of ionic (2.0.0-rc.4):https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Don't forget to follow the instructions on the breaking changes in ionic-app-scripts.